# Tab Handling in Mvvmcross with MvxTabsFragmentActivity and MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: tabs, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am writing an Android app with a tab. I was following the old method in the sample "FragmentSample". It was working fine but I am evaluating to switch to viewpager.

In FragmentSample:

- TabViewModel creates an instance of viewmodel for each individual tab
  (Vm1, Vm2...).
- In TabView, each tab fragment (Tab1Fragment,
  Tab2Fragment...) are explicitly associated to the viewmodel (Vm1,
  Vm2...) created in TabViewModel.
- It is perfect as I could do some navigation initialization to Vm1,
  Vm2 in TabViewModel.

  ```
  public class TabViewModel : BaseViewModel
  {
      public TabViewModel()
      {
          Vm1 = Mvx.IocConstruct<FirstTabViewModel>();
          Vm2 = Mvx.IocConstruct<SecondTabViewModel>();
          Vm3 = Mvx.IocConstruct<ThirdTabViewModel>();
      }

      public BaseViewModel Vm1 { get; set; }
      public BaseViewModel Vm2 { get; set; }
      public BaseViewModel Vm3 { get; set; }
  }

  public class TabView : MvxTabsFragmentActivity
  {
      public TabViewModel TabViewModel
      {
          get { return (TabViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
      }

      public TabView()
          : base(Resource.Layout.Page_TabView, Resource.Id.actualtabcontent)
      {
      }

      protected override void AddTabs(Bundle args)
      {
          AddTab<Tab1Fragment>("Tab1", "Tab 1", args, TabViewModel.Vm1);
          AddTab<Tab2Fragment>("Tab2", "Tab 2", args, TabViewModel.Vm2);
          // note that
          AddTab<Tab3Fragment>("Tab3.1", "Tab 3.1", args, TabViewModel.Vm3);
          AddTab<Tab3Fragment>("Tab3.2", "Tab 3.2", args, TabViewModel.Vm3);
          AddTab<Tab3BigFragment>("Tab3.3", "Tab 3.3", args, TabViewModel.Vm3);
      }
  }
  ```

In the latest sample project "Example" in MvvmCross-All:

- ExampleViewPagerStateViewModel create an instance of RecyclerViewModel
- ExampleViewPagerStateFragment defines the tabs (RecyclerView
  1...5) with MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter.
- When MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter is executed, another
  instance of RecyclerViewModel will be created
- RecyclerViewModel created in ExampleViewPagerStateViewModel seems to
  be completely irrelevant to the tab built. I commented out the
  creation in ExampleViewPagerStateViewModel and there was no change to
  the app behavior.
- RecyclerViewModel was created twice. It is the same in
  ExampleViewPagerFragment in the same project, and in the old version
  of this sample XPlatformMenus.

  ```
  public class ExampleViewPagerStateViewModel
      : MvxViewModel
  {
      public RecyclerViewModel Recycler { get; private set; }

      public ExampleViewPagerStateViewModel()
      {
          Recycler = new RecyclerViewModel();
      }
  }

  public class ExampleViewPagerStateFragment : BaseStateFragment<ExampleViewPagerStateViewModel>
  {
      protected override int FragmentId => Resource.Layout.fragment_example_viewpager_state;

      public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
          var view = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

          var viewPager = view.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
          if (viewPager != null)
          {
              var fragments = new List<MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter.FragmentInfo>
              {
                  //new MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter.FragmentInfo("RecyclerView 1", typeof (RecyclerViewFragment),
   //                                                                  typeof (RecyclerViewModel)),
                  //new MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter.FragmentInfo("RecyclerView 2", typeof (RecyclerViewFragment),
   //                                                                  typeof (RecyclerViewModel)),
                  //new MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter.FragmentInfo("RecyclerView 3", typeof (RecyclerViewFragment),
   //                                                                  typeof (RecyclerViewModel)),
                  //new MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter.FragmentInfo("RecyclerView 4", typeof (RecyclerViewFragment),
   //                                                                  typeof (RecyclerViewModel)),
              new MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter.FragmentInfo("RecyclerView 5", typeof (RecyclerViewFragment),
                                                                 typeof (RecyclerViewModel))
          };
              viewPager.Adapter = new MvxCachingFragmentStatePagerAdapter(Activity, ChildFragmentManager, fragments);
          }

          var tabLayout = view.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabs);
          tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);

          return view;
      }
  }
  ```

My questions are:

- What is the usage of creating RecyclerViewModel in
  ExampleViewPagerStateViewModel in "Example"?
- In FragmentSample, Tab3.1 Tab3.2 Tab3.3 are sharing the same Vm3. Can
  I do the same thing with ViewPager? Is there any way I can specify
  the tab view (RecyclerView 1...5) to associate to the
  RecyclerViewModel created in ExampleViewPagerStateViewModel but not a
  new instance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just found that it could be done by changing the third parameter of FragmentInfo to Recycler created in RecyclerViewModel. The sample should make the change.